# How does a program locate the index of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I know array lookup has O(1) time, so it cannot be looping through. Does the program store the memory locations of the indices of the array, or how does it look the index instantaneously?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array elements are always spaced at equal distances in the memory, so finding an element given an index requires a multiplication by the size of the element and an addition of the array's base in memory. Both operations are often done within the space of a single instruction in hardware by employing an appropriate addressing mode.

Answer (score 3):

underneath...
its a memory address + (index postion * the size of the things in the array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`1. Arrays are consecutive memory locations which are stored in Heap, as Arrays are` `objects in java.`

`2. Assume i have an Array of String as an instance variable`

String[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

Now its like this

arr[0] = 1

arr[1] = 2

arr[2] = 3

arr[3] = 4

arr[4] = 5

`{1,2,3,4,5} are stored over the heap, and Considering array "arr" as instance` `variable, will lives within the object on the heap.`

`Now` **arr will hold the address of the very first element of the Array that is 1**. **"arr" which is an object reference array variable, will be inside the object, and {1,2,3,4,5} outside somewhere on the heap.**

Answer (score 0):

Array elements are stored in a consecutive block, if they grow they need to be moved to a new place. The elements are then accessed using an offset from where the array begins.

In C you can access the element of index *i* in an array called *a* using two different methods:

- `int arrayElement = a[i];`
- `int arrayElement = (int)(a + i * sizeof(int));`

This is more or less how it is done in Java under the hood.